# QSqlQuery prepared SELECT statement fails on exec()

Tags: qt, select, exec, prepared-statement

The following code fails on `QSqlQuery::exec()`. When I run the query without the prepared statement argument, it returns the correct results, available as one would expect through `QSqlQuery::next()`

`executedQuery()` reports that `":username"` was in fact not replaced by the argument, but with a `?` (Is it supposed to, since the query did not execute successfully?).

`db_` is a QSqlDatabase class variable and `isOpen()` reports `true`. The Qt framework verison is 4.7.3.

```
DBSql::userInfo(const QString &username, 
                QString &passwd, 
                QString &name, 
                UserPriv priv)
{
  QSqlQuery userQuery(db_);
  const QString userStr("SELECT u.id, u.fullname, u.password, p.description \
                        FROM users u INNER JOIN privilege p ON u.privilege_id = p.id \
                      WHERE u.username = :username");
  userQuery.bindValue(":username", username);

  if (!userQuery.prepare(userStr))
    std::cout << "prepare failed" << std::endl;

  if (userQuery.exec()) {
    while (userQuery.next()) {
      userId = userQuery.value(0).toInt();
      name = userQuery.value(1).toString();
      passwd = userQuery.value(2).toString();
      const QString privilegeDesc = userQuery.value(3).toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try to call the prepare method before binding value

Comment: You are leaking your QSqlQuery resource. You should probably use a simple automatic variable : `QSqlQuery userQuery(db_);`

Comment: Edited, and thanks. It was originally not written with heap allocation, but I tried that as a sort of desperate last resort to see if the behaviour changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `userQuery->prepare(userStr)` before `userQuery->bindValue(":username", username)`

Comment: You are correct, sir. Confirmed. :) How do I upvote your answer? It says i need 15 reputation to do so.